# Trying to pull through P tags from render section to place else where

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm using rendersection in MVC. Is it possible to store any paragraph tags seperately in a seperate variable. My current code is this

```
var menuText1= RenderSection("text`", false).ToHtmlString();
```

and i push the content on the front end like this:

```
@Html.Raw(menuText1)
```

The actuall content in menuText1 consists of several anchor tags and one paragraph tag is possible to pull through both sets of content seperately

Comment: If you are willing to use a DOM Parser the HTML Agility Pack is one way to go.. you can load your html in HTML Document object and then get all you <p> tags and <a> tags. I'll provide an example if needed.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would consider using a DOM Parser. You can install HTML Agility Pack from [HTML Agility Pack Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

Once installed you can load your HTML in the HTML Document Object. Then you can get the tags as shown below.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("Your HTML");

var pTags = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p").ToList();
var aTags = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").ToList();
```

Hope that can help!